# extract kmz file with php

Tags: php, kml, kmz

Hi I want to extract a KMZ file that has an Images folder with some images and a kml file

**Other questions here just have the kml file but mine has a images folder too!**
how can I extract it?
I tried this but it didn't work

```
$data = file_get_contents("test/test.kmz"); // url of the KMZ file
file_put_contents("/test/kmz_temp",$data);
ob_start();
passthru('unzip -p /test/kmz_temp');
$xml_data = ob_get_clean();
header("Content-type: text/xml");
dd($xml_data);
```

and also this

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test/test.kmz');
$zip->extractTo('/test/public');
$zip->close();**strong text**
```

Comment: in your second example on line 3 remove the last close parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution

if you change the format of the file (while moving it to your folder) to zip it will extract it